# What is the latest supported version of MySQL that works with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'd like to update MySQL due to security vulnerabilities, however I cannot find a compatibility matrix from IBM showing which versions of MySQL are officially supported for 7.0/7.1 etc

Currently using:

- MySQL 5.6.240
- Worklight Server 7.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest supported version of MySQL is 5.6
http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=4DB072503A2F11E396F9FC10E99BE807#sw-3

Comment: Thanks - from the site: 5.5 and future fix packs/5.6 and future fix packs

Comment: Fix packs mean 5.6.x, not 5.7. Just FYI.